# Write name of file before a pattern inside that file

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics

I have thousands of similar files and I'd like to write their respective names after a pattern inside them. For example:

**file 1's name is nexus0000

inside the file there is:

```
>Pseudomonas_1M
ATGATCCGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCAAACGCTATC
>Pseudomonas_2M
GTGAGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCGAGCCGCTATC
```

and I want to get this:

```
nexus0000>Pseudomonas_1M
ATGATCCGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCAAACGCTATC
nexus0000>Pseudomonas_2M
GTGAGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCGAGCCGCTATC
```

**file 2's name is nexus0001

inside the file there is:

```
>Pseudomonas_1M
ATGATCCGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCAAACGCTATC
>Pseudomonas_2M
GTGAGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCGAGCCGCTATC
```

and I want to get this:

```
nexus0001>Pseudomonas_1M
ATGATCCGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCAAACGCTATC
nexus0001>Pseudomonas_2M
GTGAGCTTCGAGCAGGTCGGCGAGCCGCTATC
```

etc.

Up to this point, I've only managed to write the name of the file in the first line using:

```
for file in nexus*; do echo "$file"$"$(cat -- "$file")" > "$file"; done
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***sed*** solution:

```
for f in nexus*; do sed -i "s/^>/$f&/" "$f"; done
```

---

Or using ***gawk*** and its `inplace` extension (available since v. 4.1.0):

```
for f in nexus*; do awk -i inplace '/^>/{ $0=FILENAME$0 }1' "$f"; done
```

Comment: I ended up using your sed solution. Worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name nexus\* -exec perl -i'' -pe 's/^>/$ARGV>/' {} +
```

We launch a `find` only for the current directory, looking for regular files, names beginning with `nexus` and then perform an in-place editing of multiple such files by replacing the `>` found at the beginning of line with filename + itself.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with perl one-liner like so:

```
perl -i -pe 's/>/$ARGV$_/g' nexus*
```

Note that `-i` alters the file in-place, so if you want to only test the command, run it without `-i` flag first.

Comment: ITYM `$&` in place of `$_`. If there are mulitple `>`s in a line, the output would be ... horrendous due to that `/g` modifier. You could just say: `perl -pi -e 's/^(?=>)/$ARGV/' nexus*`